# Python Tkinter canvas.scale() does not scale images while running

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, python-imaging-library

I am new with Tkinter, and could not find any answers on why the scaling does not work.

I have a script that moves and zooms on an image while the window is running. The movement works perfectly, although **canvas.scale()** doesn't do anything.

Here is a snippet:

```
def GetAttrPositions(char, attrs):
    global pos
    pos = [10,10,1]
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Getting Attribute Positions')
    root.geometry(f"{char_base.size[0]}x{char_base.size[1]}")

    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=2000, height=2000)
    canvas.pack()

    char = tk.PhotoImage(file=f"assets/Chars/{char}.png")
    char_image = canvas.create_image(0,0, anchor=tk.NW, image=char)
    attr = tk.PhotoImage(file=f"assets/Attr/{attrs[0]['Type']}/{attrs[0]['Name']}.png")
    attr_image = canvas.create_image(pos[0], pos[1], anchor=tk.NW, image=attr)
    
    def move(event):
        global pos
        if event.char == "a":
            print('a')
            pos[0] -= 2
            canvas.move(attr_image, -2, 0)
        elif event.char == "d":
            print('d')
            pos[0] += 2
            canvas.move(attr_image, 2, 0)
        elif event.char == "w":
            print('w')
            pos[1] -= 2
            canvas.move(attr_image, 0, -2)
        elif event.char == "s":
            print('s')
            pos[1] += 2
            canvas.move(attr_image, 0, 2)
        elif event.char == "x":
            print('x')
            pos[2] = pos[2]*2
            canvas.scale(attr_image, pos[0], pos[1], 2, 2)
        elif event.char == "z":
            print('z')
            pos[2] = pos[2]/2
            canvas.scale(attr_image, pos[0], pos[1], 0.5, 0.5)

    root.bind("<Key>", move)
    root.mainloop()
```

P.S. I am sure that it is working, as if I put a wrong offset, then the image moves, but does not scale

Comment: _"Python Tkinter canvas.scale() does not scale images"_ - That is correct, it's not designed to scale images. I think there are several questions on this site that ask about scaling images, have you searched for them and tried to apply what they suggest?

Comment: @BryanOakley I could not find any appropriate posts that allow to scale the image in realtime by button presses, as all of them reccomend using PIL before starting the window. If you know a post that explains it, it would be much appreciated

Comment: The same techniques apply whether using a button or doing it as a window is resized. You'll have to use PIL since tkinter  can only halve or double the size of images.